# Where to get detail description on understanding android

Tags: android

I found lots of books on android which give basic concept on android Example (calling Activity, Intent, service, broadcast receivers etc). But I want to know brief description on all these concept. in os level or in api level how does it work. Also how connection with wifi or 3g works in api level.

I want to know brief understanding on android. Can anyone suggest any tutorial or book to get detail understanding on android.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start with the Android Developer's Guide. http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Comment: I have gone through this url and started programming but i was unable to understand the internal architecture. But unable to understand How each and everything works

Comment: I would also advice to start with the DevGuide. This really has the most comprehensive overview of the Application Fundamentals. You might have to read it several times before you really get it, but it's worth the trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to buy a book. For me Professional Android 2 Application Development was really good. But probably now there is better (up to date) alternative.

Anyway I find reading books much easier starter than separate tutorials and articles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a really detailed view, just look at the source code.